# What is the best first development to purchase in Roll Through the Ages?

Tags: openings, roll-through-the-ages

Played my first 4 player game of **Roll Through the Ages** <sup>[official](http://rollthroughtheages.com/index.php)</sup> last night.  I've played the solo game quite a bit but I quickly discovered that the multiplayer game plays a bit differently!

What development should be purchased first and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I'm assuming you're playing The Late Bronze Age version (which is far superior to the game as sold off-the shelf – It's very clear that The Late Bronze Age version of the game is what was originally presented to the publishers, and they felt the need to "simplify" it to reach a wider audience by removing several really nifty mechanics).

Given that, **Irrigation** is the simplest first pick, although **Leadership** can be almost as good, if you're a little lucky and use it well.  If you can leapfrog to **Quarrying**, that's a great start (it'll help you buy better advancements, and it combos very well with **Engineering** and **Architecture** later in the game).  If you're playing with three or four players, get **Medicine** ASAP.  It *will*  save you at least 3 points in penalties.

...and that's my 2 cents.

Answer (score 10):

@invisiblejon -
The Late Bronze Age was developed months after the game as sold in the box. I added some additional developments for those gamers looking for something meatier. (The publisher didn't water anything down.)

...and I like Irrigation as a first purchase too!

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the input and welcome to the site!  You wrote a great game in Roll through the Ages.

Comment: Late Bronze Age was developed later?  I'm astonished!  It meshes so perfectly with the point structure of the game, and provides uses for each previously unused resource so smoothly that...  Well, wow.

Answer (score 3):

In my games, I almost always purchase Irrigation first, because Drought can be really devastating to your score and Irrigation provides some defense against the fact that you can't reroll skulls in multiplayer.

Comment: Can't reroll skulls in multiplayer?  Ooops!  I see I have to reread the rules a bit closer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pat - I **highly** recommend the iPhone app - it's the only version of the game I have every played! However, the documentation in the app is sort of on the thin side. So imagine my surprise discovering that rule after using my experience in single-player to explain the rules to my lovely bride - for a multiplayer game! :)

Comment: I picked up the app for my iPad due to a recommendation here, I think from you.  Thanks!  I bought the boardgame the next week.

Comment: I really sucked at the iPhone app for a while (compared to my friends) because I knew that you couldn't re-roll skulls. I didn't understand why the app didn't automatically freeze them for you. My surprise went the other way, and my scores improved significantly.

Comment: @Matt - Ha, so either way you go, switching from one version to the other will mess ya up :)

Answer (score 0):

I start off with Quarrying if possible.  It can rack up a lot of money towards developments.  Even if you only get an extra "bump" per turn (as opposed to one extra "bump" moving on the Stone track, when you acquire up 7+ goods), it's still a good chunk of money.

When you or other players roll more Empire Dice, then get some protection against, those Disasters.